# vim swap substrings while using a wildcard in search and replace

Tags: regex, vim, replace

Say I have a string `Test<A Class Name>` and I want to have `<A Class Name>Test`. I am trying something along the lines of:

```
%s/Test.*/&Test/g
```

However, this gives me `<A Class Name>TestTest` since the entire string was matched. How can I change the line above to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a capturing group, like this:

```
%s/Test\([^[:space:]]\+\)/\1Test/g
```

`\([^[:space:]]\+\)` captures all non spaces characters after *Test* into capturing group `1`. `\1Test` reassembles it in reverse order.

Comment: Running that on TestMosSliSystem gives MoTestsSliSystem, but you have  given me a different path. Thank you. +1. Is this because the + is not greedy?

Comment: Oh! Use `[:space:]` instead of `\s`

Comment: yum that got it. Thank you, for the explanation and the correction.

Comment: You are welcome! Never knew that `\s` does not work for *whitespace characters* in vim! :)

Comment: It could because I am in Windows on cygwin. Perhaps it would of worked if I was in a linux distribution. I will try the \s when I reboot.

Comment: No, it doesn't work on Linux as well. The `\s` will be treated as a literal *s*. I just didn't got aware of that because I've tested with `TestFoo` which does not contain an *s*. :)